# Debug Launch Error

Tags: visual-studio-code

Rapidly iterating through some changes this afternoon and at some point restarted the debugger on my node app in VS Code and it didn't fully come up.  Checking the OUTPUT I see this:  "attempt to send more than one response for command launchERROR: The process "6584" not found"  Any thoughts on what this means or how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Still not exactly sure what the issue was but I copied the code to a new directory and it worked fine.    I also did a fresh pull from git in a new directory and it worked fine.  So something got dorked up in the environment but I couldn't pin down exactly what.